# Forking inside loop preventing iterator from incrementing with Parallel::Prefork

Tags: perl, iterator, fork

I have some code where I expect the output to be 1 and 6, but instead it outputs 1 ad infinitum.

```
use v5.10;
use Parallel::Prefork;
use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );
use POSIX qw( ceil );

my $forks = 2;

my @numbers       = (1..10);
my $chunk_size    = ceil((scalar @numbers) / $forks);
my $game_iterator = natatime $chunk_size, @numbers;
my $fm            = Parallel::Prefork->new({ max_workers => $forks });

while ($fm->signal_received ne 'TERM') {
  while( my @numbers_chunk = $game_iterator->() ) { 
    $fm->start(sub {
        say $numbers_chunk[0];
    });
  }
}

$fm->wait_all_children;

# bash-4.2$ perl test.pl
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# etc
```

Where the above script splits an array of 10 numbers into $fork number of arrays (2) and is supposed to pass each of those arrays to their own fork for processing.

If you replace `$fm->start(sub {say $numbers_chunk[0];});` with just `say $numbers_chunk[0];` the correct result is shown. Parallel::ForkManager also outputs the correct result (following the synopsis) so I don't know if i'm doing something incorrectly or if this is  a bug in the module.

The ForkManager script that outputs the expected results:

```
use v5.10;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );
use POSIX qw( ceil );

my $forks = 2;

my @numbers       = (1..10);
my $chunk_size    = ceil((scalar @numbers) / $forks);
my $game_iterator = natatime $chunk_size, @numbers;
my $fm            = Parallel::ForkManager->new($forks );

while( my @numbers_chunk = $game_iterator->() ) { 
  $fm->start and next;
  say $numbers_chunk[0];
  $fm->finish;
}

$fm->wait_all_children;


# bash-4.2$ perl test.pl
# 1
# 6
```

Comment: Running with `Devel::Trace` and `Devel::Trace::Fork`, I see that `$game_iterator->()` is only getting called one time.

Comment: In fact, your program never gets out of the first `while` loop in the [`Parallel::Prefork::start`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KAZUHO/Parallel-Prefork-0.14/lib/Parallel/Prefork.pm) method.

Comment: I'd also like to note that the order of the two `while` loops in the first example can be switched to get the same result.

Comment: btw, `while ($fm->signal_received ne 'TERM')` makes no sense since you didn't instruct `$fm` to trap TERM.

Comment: the pod for Parallel::Prefork doesn't state it, but its constructor contains `trap_signals => { TERM => 'TERM', },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to the documentation, Parallel::Prefork is *very* different than Parallel::ForkManager. It's designed to be used by something like a web server, which loads a config once then just spawns identical children until it's shut down by a signal.

As such, `start` keeps creating children as needed, and doesn't return until a signal meant to terminate the whole process is caught.

That said, it is possible to make P::Prefork work like a fat version of P::ForkManager by using `before_fork`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use List::MoreUtils   qw( natatime );
use Parallel::Prefork qw( );
use POSIX             qw( ceil );

my $forks = 2;

my @numbers       = (1..10);
my $chunk_size    = ceil(@numbers / $forks);
my $game_iterator = natatime($chunk_size, @numbers);

my @numbers_chunk;

my $fm = Parallel::Prefork->new({
   max_workers => $forks,
   trap_signals => { TERM => 'TERM' },
   before_fork => sub {
      @numbers_chunk = $game_iterator->()
         or kill(TERM => $$);
   },
});

$fm->start(sub {
   say $numbers_chunk[0];
});

$fm->wait_all_children();
```

But why not just use Parallel::ForkManager instead of forcing Parallel::Prefork to emulate it?

Comment: I was using ForkManager, but a cpan review led me to believe Prefork would be an easy solution to stopping all child processes when I send a term signal. I will handle it myself and use ForkManager I suppose.

Comment: Oh I see. Then go ahead and use Prefork

Answer (score 1):

[Parallel::Prefork](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3A%3APrefork) is designed for independent stateless, restartable workers processes that do not require data from the parent process. The module does not provide a facility for threading data to the callback, which makes setting up communication channels—such as for passing chunks of numbers—awkward.

In comparison to the simpler program below that calls `fork` directly, the module does not seem to buy you anything.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use v5.10;
use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );
use POSIX qw( ceil WNOHANG );

my $forks = 2;

my @numbers       = (1 .. 10);
my $chunk_size    = ceil(scalar @numbers / $forks);
my $game_iterator = natatime $chunk_size, @numbers;

for (1 .. $forks) {
  if (my @numbers_chunk = $game_iterator->()) {
    unless (fork // die "$0: fork: $!") {
      say $numbers_chunk[0];
      exit 0;
    }
  }
}

# wait for all child processes
my $pid;
do { $pid = waitpid -1, WNOHANG } while $pid > 0;
```

You might work around the design constraints of Parallel::Prefork by using System V IPC, *e.g.*, with a message queue as in the code below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Parallel::Prefork;
use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );
use POSIX qw( ceil );
use IPC::SysV qw(IPC_NOWAIT IPC_PRIVATE S_IRUSR S_IWUSR);
use IPC::Msg;
use Errno qw( ENOMSG );

my $forks = 3;

my @numbers       = (1 .. 20);
my $chunk_size    = ceil((scalar @numbers) / $forks);
my $game_iterator = natatime $chunk_size, @numbers;
my $fm            = Parallel::Prefork->new({ max_workers => $forks });

my $maxsize = 0;
my $msg = new IPC::Msg(IPC_PRIVATE, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
while (my @numbers_chunk = $game_iterator->()) {
  my $chunk = join " ", @numbers_chunk;
  $msg->snd(1, $chunk) or die "$0: msgsnd: $!";
  $maxsize = length $chunk if length $chunk > $maxsize;
}

my $ppid = $$;

while ($fm->signal_received ne 'TERM') {
  $fm->start(sub {
    my $ok = $msg->rcv(my $buf, $maxsize, 1, IPC_NOWAIT);
    if (!$ok) {
      if ($!{ENOMSG}) {
        sleep 1;  # XXX: poor man's synchronization
        kill TERM => $ppid or die "$0: kill: $!";
        return;
      }
      die "$0: msgrcv: $!";
    }
    print "[$$]: got '$buf'\n";
  });
}

$fm->wait_all_children;
```

This implementation is passable because all the processes use the same global message queue object.

Sample output:

```
[31198]: got '8 9 10 11 12 13 14'
[31197]: got '1 2 3 4 5 6 7'
[31200]: got '15 16 17 18 19 20'
```

As the code above demonstrates, you really want an abstraction better suited to your problem than what Parallel::Prefork provides.

Comment: The nodes don't share information between them, they are simply started with a different set of data to work on. Note the Parallel::ForkManager example code. The Parallel::Prefork itself claims it 'is much like Parallel::ForkManager, but supports graceful shutdown and run-time reconfiguration'